# RAML Osprey-Mock-Service TypeError: Cannot read property 'absolutePath' of null

Tags: raml

I seem to be having an issue using the osprey-mock-service for RAML 1.0 when I try to us the "uses" within a DataType. The RAML is valid based on the API Workbench and using raml-cop. Below is a sample of the DataType that I have and the error message I'm getting. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there is an issue with the mock service. If I don't use the "uses" in the datatype everything works fine.

RAML:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
uses:
 StandardTypes: ../standard-types.raml

type: !include ../entity.raml
properties:
 firstName: string
 lastName: string
 birthDate: string
 phone: StandardTypes.Phone
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'absolutePath' of null
at LowLevelWrapperForTypeSystem.children (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-1-parser\dist\parser\highLevelImpl.js:1011:75)
at parse (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-typesystem\dist\src\parse.js:784:18)
at AccumulatingRegistry.get (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-typesystem\dist\src\parse.js:257:30)
at C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-typesystem\dist\src\parse.js:375:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.parseTypeCollection (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-typesystem\dist\src\parse.js:374:74)
at Object.parseFromAST (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-typesystem\dist\src\index.js:89:15)
at ASTNodeImpl.types (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-1-parser\dist\parser\highLevelImpl.js:1280:38)
at ASTNodeImpl.types (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-1-parser\dist\parser\highLevelImpl.js:1223:49)
at ASTNodeImpl.types (C:\Users\greg.smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\osprey-mock-service\node_modules\raml-1-parser\dist\parser\highLevelImpl.js:1223:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure-out what may cause this based on the snippet and log you sent. I tried to reproduce using that exact same DataType, created a `standard-types.raml` Library, a `entity.raml` DataType, put them both in an upper directory, then I `!include`d your DataType in an `api.raml`, passed it to `osprey-mock-service` and it worked just fine.